# What is an "addressed member"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Sentence in question: (From [DailyMail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12231987/New-York-City-explodes-rainbow-colors-partygoers-descend-closed-avenues-Pride.html))

> Notable figures taking part in the colorful procession included
> Governor Kathy Hochul, Chuck Schumer, Reverend Al Sharpton and New
> York Attorney General Letitia James, who joined the governor as
> **addressed members of the crowd**

According to Wiktionary, the most possible meaning of [addressed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addressed) in this context is:

> Having been the audience for an address, speech or presentation.

But according to the picture, Governor Kathy Hochul and others notable figures were giving speeches not receiving speeches.

What does "*addressed members of the crowd*" mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it arose from a typographical error.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It wouldn't be particularly idiomatic, but the text as given is syntactically valid - with the meaning that Schumer, Sharpton and James (who were in the audience *as well as the governor*), were specifically *acknowledged by name, and **addressed*** (spoken to) by an unspecified speaker in the procession. Just sayin'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, I agree about that, but in the _Daily Mail_?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why don't you point out the exact `typographical error` you mentioned? It could be much more helpful. We can't afford to be ambiguous - that doesn't solve problems.

Comment: @J.Joe - James K has clearly identified the typing/typographical error, which is the omission of 'the' between 'addressed' and 'members'.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is just a mistake.  There's a word missing, probably something like

> ...who joined the governor as she addressed members of the crowd.

That is "addressed" is the past tense, and not a participle or adjective.